# java game loop sprites map rendering

Tags: java

I have class which is extending `Canvas`, this is my constructor:

```
public Game() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game");

        JPanel panel = (JPanel) frame.getContentPane();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 600));
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        setBounds(0, 0, 1000, 600);
        setIgnoreRepaint(true);

        frame.add(this);


        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        setFocusable(true);
        addKeyListener(this);

        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("img.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
```

This is loop

```
try {
    this.repaint();
    Thread.sleep(17);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and paint method

```
super.paint(g);
for (int i = 0; i < map.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < map[0].length; j++) {
        Tile current = map[i][j];
        g.drawImage(img, i * 32, j * 32, this);
    }
}
```

It draws normally, but while it's updating every 17 miliseconds it's just like lagging. I can see how it cleares and draws each time. How to fix this "fps drop" or whatever is it?

Comment: If you are using a Canvas, then you should be using a BufferStrategy instead of overwriting paint. Render you tile map directly to a BufferedImage and paint it instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `java.awt.Canvas`, you should be painting using a [`java.awt.image.BufferStrategy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html) instead of overriding `paint`.

`Canvas` is not double buffered to start with, but the point of using a `Canvas` is to get access to the `BufferStrategy`, which provides double buffering capabilities, active painting control and closer access to the hardware.

Instead of repainting the entire map on each paint cycle, you should render the tile map to a `BufferedImage` and paint the image instead